# FTP Server Administrative Interface via Web

Tags: ftp, webdav, interface

I am working on creating an FTP server ... I need to administer it via an online web interface.

I tried http://proftpd-adm.sourceforge.net/ but I couldn't get it to work.

I have even considered moving to a webdav configuration except I couldn't find any online administration tools for that ...

Anyone have any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webmin provides a web interface for ProFTPd.

http://www.webmin.com/standard.html